# Тавтология в тексте с подзаголовком

Tags: стилистика

Считается ли использование однокоренных слов в подзаголовке и в следом идущем предложении текста тавтологией?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Тавтология — речевая ошибка, заключающаяся в неоправданном употреблениии однокоренных слов в одном или соседних предложениях. Например: *Относительно данного замечания **следует** сказать **следующее***.

Заглавие часто не рассматривается как неотъемлемая часть текста: его почти всегда можно отбросить, и ущерба смыслу не будет. Иногда даже встречается подобная структура:

> ### Паша
>
> Паша любил дергать девочек за косички...
>
> ### Саша
>
> Что же сказать о Саше? Она была хорошей ученицей...

Таким образом, обычно заголовок и следующее за ним предложение могут содержать однокоренные слова, при этом не являясь тавтологичными.

Answer (score 0):

Тавтологией при очень большом желании посчитать можно (хотя я бы не стал), но даже в этом случае речевой ошибки здесь не будет. В 90% случаев тавтология является ошибкой только тогда, когда она ещё и плеоназм, в данном случае это скорее всего не так.